# How do you fix the Silverlight application shift that occurs in the Firefox browser?

Tags: silverlight, firefox, xaml

Currently I have an Silverlight application that when run on Firefox browser (ver 3.6) the entire contents of the Silverlight application shifts a little, and also the scrollbars on both the bottom and the side appear when I first use it. This does not happen in IE 8.  How can I fix this in Firefox so it doesn't happen?  The project type I created was the "Silverlight 3 Application + Website" via Expression Blend 3.  This the code I am using in my MainPage.xaml:

```
<UserControl
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 x:Class="StackoverflowExample.MainPage"
 Width="640" Height="480">

 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Green">
  <Rectangle Fill="#FFBB2020" Stroke="Black" Margin="155,58,266,178"/>
  <Button Margin="199,180,302,236" Content="Button"/>
 </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because Firefox draws a 1px dashed border around the element with 100% width and height when you click on it, making it too large for the window to fit by just 1px. You can fix this with the solution I found [here](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/forum/1/564700):

> Yes, quite annoying indeed.
>
> Could somebody tell us wether this is on purpose or wether it's a bug, please?
>
> I've been using:
>
> :focus {
>      outline: 0;
>   }
>
> Do we need to find a new trick?

You don't necessarily need the `:focus` pseudo-class, you can just set the style of the `<object>` to use the `outline: 0;`.

Comment: You led me to the correct location but I used this instead:
a:focus, object:focus {
outline: none;
-moz-outline-style: none;
}